# How to pass Eloquent data with relation to vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-blade

i'm trying to pass model relation from blade, to vue.js template.

I have 2 models with relation, shortly:

```
class Emails extends Model
{
   public function template()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Template::class);
   }
}
```

and the other one with `has many` relation.

With such request `$mails = Emails::all();` i can reach templates using blade after foreach like `$mail->template`.

But if i pass it to vue.js template `<sometemplate :mails="{{$mails}}"`, after foreach `mail.template` would be empty.

I know, that i'm doing something wrong, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, found my solution. I had to add `with('template') to my request`